# Iterate throught n-dimensional vector c++

Tags: c++, pointers, n-dimensional

I wanted to write my own code to iterate over an n dimensional vector (where the dimension is known). Here is the code:

```cpp
void printing(const auto& i, const int dimension){
    int k= dimension;
    for(const auto& j: i){
        if(k>1){
            cout<<"k: "<<k<<endl;
            printing(j, --k);
        }
        else{
            //start printing
            cout<<setw(3);
            cout<<j; //not quite sure about this line
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
main.cpp:21:5: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
 for(const auto& j: i){
 ^~~
```

Could someone help me to correct it or give me a better way to print the vector?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are the number of dimensions known at _compile-time_? And is it always known that `const auto& i` will be a `std::vector` type? depending on your answers, this might be able to be solved much simpler using templates

Comment: The number of Dimensions are known at compile time. About the second question: I would use the function only with vectors but with different dimensions (I mean 2d vector, 3d vector...). Example:
    vector<vector<int> > myVector={{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}}; 
    printing(myVector, 2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dimensions are known at compile-time, this can be solved easily with a `template` that takes dimensions as the non-type argument.

```cpp
template <std::size_t Dimensions>
void printing(const auto& i){
    if constexpr (Dimensions != 0) {
        for(const auto& j: i){
            // I'm not sure if it is intentional to print 'k' each iteration, 
            // but this is kept for consistency with the question
            cout<<"k: " << Dimensions << endl;
            printing<Dimensions - 1u>(j);
        }
    } else {
        cout << setw(3);
        cout << j;
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The use would be, for a 2d vector:

```cpp
printing<2>(vec);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MzY9nj3Gz)</kbd>

---

However, if you always know that `const auto& i` will be a `std::vector` type, you can potentially solve this even easier by just not using `auto` arguments at all, and instead use `template` matching:

```cpp
// called only for the vector values
template <typename T>
void printing(const std::vector<T>& i){
    for(const auto& j: i){
        // possibly compute 'k' to print -- see below
        printing(j);
    }
}

// Only called for non-vector values
template <typename T>
void printing(const T& v) {
    cout << setw(3);
    cout << v;
    cout << '\n';
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8f9994v3K)</kbd>

To compute the "dimension" of the vector, you can write a recursive type-trait for that:

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // std::integral_constant

// Base case: return the count
template <std::size_t Count, typename T>
struct vector_dimension_impl
  : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Count> {};
 
// Recursive case: add 1 to the count, and check inner type
template <std::size_t Count, typename T, typename Allocator>
struct vector_dimension_impl<Count, std::vector<T,Allocator>> 
  : vector_dimension_impl<Count + 1u, T> {};

// Dispatcher
template <typename T>
struct vector_dimension : vector_dimension_impl<0u, T> {};

// Convenience access
template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto vector_dimension_v = vector_dimension<T>::value;
 
// Simple tests:
static_assert(vector_dimension_v<std::vector<int>> == 1u);
static_assert(vector_dimension_v<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> == 2u);
static_assert(vector_dimension_v<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>> == 3u);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rb1b9TrzP)</kbd>

With the above recursive trait, you can get the "dimension" of each `template`d vector type, without requiring the user to pass in the value at all.

If you still wanted to print `k:`  each time, you can use the above simply with:

```cpp
cout << "k: " << vector_dimension_v<T> << endl;
```

This only works if the type is known to be a `vector` -- but it could be written using concepts to work with anything following the abstract definition of something like a `vector` as well.

If you want this to work with *any* range-like type, then you could replace the `vector`-overload with a `requires(std::ranges::range<T>)` instead, and change the template-specializations for finding the dimension to also use the same. I won't pollute the answer with all this code since it's largely the same as above -- but I'll link to it in action below:

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x68Efxq5n)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I loved the second solution that you provided. I do have a last question thought: How can I improve myself in C++ ? What book would you advise me to buy?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a function that can print any n-dimensional iterable container:

```cpp
template<typename Object, typename Iterable>
void Print(
    const Iterable& iterable,
    const string& separatorDimensions = "\n",
    const function<void(const Object&)>& funcPrintElem = [] (const Object& obj) {
        static_assert(
            is_arithmetic_v<Object> || is_same_v<remove_const_t<remove_pointer_t<Object>>, char>,
            R"(The object from the innermost range is not a built-in/c-string type, please provide a valid print element function.)"
            );
        cout << obj << ' ';
    }
) {
    if constexpr (ranges::range<Iterable>) {
        ranges::for_each(iterable, [&] (const auto& it) { Print(it, separatorDimensions, funcPrintElem); });
        cout << separatorDimensions;
    } else {
        funcPrintElem(iterable);
    }
}
```

The function has a default **std::function** that can print any built-in type like **int**, **unsigned char**, **long long** etc... and the c-string like **char*** or **const char***, if you have another object like a **pair** or **tuple** or an object of your class you can pass a function that prints your object.

You can use the function like this: (you must explicitly tell the function your inner most object like below)

```cpp
int main() {
    cout << "v: " << endl;
    vector<uint16_t> v { 1, 2, 3 };
    Print<uint16_t>(v);

    cout << endl << "ll: " << endl;
    list<list<const char*>> ll { { "a", "b" }, { "c", "d" } };
    Print<const char*>(ll);

    struct smth {
        int a;
        char b;
    };

    cout << endl << "smths: " << endl;
    vector<smth> smths { { 14, '0' }, { 18, '1' } };
    Print<smth>(smths, "\n", [] (const smth& obj) { cout << "a = " << obj.a << ", b = " << obj.b << endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

The function can be found [here](https://github.com/ClaudiuHBann/Random_Pieces_Of_Code/blob/main/Print%20ANYTHING.cpp), maybe I will update in the future to support more things.

Edit: You need to have at least c++20 for this function to work